# How to save mpi profile summary report in matlab

Tags: matlab, profiling, profiler, parfor

I want to save the details of each worker as it is seen in the mpiprofile summary report. Profsave does not give all the details very clearly for the report generated by the mpiprofile viewer option.

Is there any other way to save the report?

Answer (score 0):

One way I figured to do something similar is the following.

I am assuming you are using "pmode" because as far as my understanding goes, you need to run on "pmode" to run mpiprofile.

So this is how it goes.

- Saving

  1. Save the mpiprofile info inside each worker(or it is often called lab from my understanding).

     mpiprofile mpistruct;
  2. Then you transfer to the client using the following command

     pmode lab2client mpistruct;
  3. Then save the mpistruct into a .mat file

     save('mpistruct');
- Loading:
  When you are trying to view the mpiprofile result:

  1. Load the mpi file

     load('mpistruct.mat');
  2. Run mpiprofile viewer

     mpiprofile('viewer', mpistruct);

This should pop up the browser.

Note. Above code was tested with 2015b.

(I wrote the same exact answer to Matlab community. I copied for your convenience.)